# Hide <td> outside <div> and know the good width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

The goal of the script is:

- retrieve a `table` inside a `div`
- at init step, hide all `td` on the right outside `div` limit
- on click next or previous, shift 1 `td` on left or right

Here the script:

```
(function(self, $) {

    options = {                                         
        //taille du wrapper 
        w_wrap: $('.grid-wrap').width(),
        //taille de la table
        w_table: $('.table').width(),
        //nb de colonnes
        nb_col: $('.table tr:nth-child(1) td').length,
        //taille de chaque colonne
        w_array_td: [],
        //index des colonnes cachés à gauche
        min_array_td_hide: [],
        //index des colonnes cachés à droite
        max_array_td_hide: []
    },              

    min_max = function(arr){
        var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
        var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
        //ici on exploite toute la puissance de la funk allemande !
        return { min: (min === min/0 ? 0 : min), max: (max === max/0 ? 0 : max)};
    },

    self.init = function (opt){
        debugger;

        var arr = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= options.nb_col; i++)
        {
            arr.push($('td:nth-child(' + i + ')').width());
        };
        options.w_array_td = arr;

        //Si la table est supérieur au container
        if (options.w_table > options.w_wrap)
        {
            //on cache les colonnes en commencant par la dernière
            var size = options.w_table;
            var c = options.nb_col;
            while (size > options.w_wrap)
            {
                $('th:nth-child(' + c + '),td:nth-child(' + c + ')').hide();
                size = size - options.w_array_td[c-1];
                options.max_array_td_hide.push(c);
                c = c - 1;                                                                  
            }
        }                                                   
        // #TODO : Si premier ou dernier, caché le lien

    },

    self.prev = function() {
        debugger;
        //get le min et le max
        var min = min_max(options.min_array_td_hide);
        var max = min_max(options.max_array_td_hide);
        // posibilité d'aller plus loin à gauche ?
        if (min.min >= 1)
        {
            //on retire 1 a gauche
            var index = min.max - 1;
            options.min_array_td_hide.push(index);
            $('th:nth-child('+index+'),td:nth-child('+index+')').hide();

            //on affiches celle de droite                                                                                                       
            options.max_array_td_hide = options.max_array_td_hide.filter(function(e) { return e !== min.max})
            $('th:nth-child(' + (min.max) + '),td:nth-child(' + (min.max) + ')').show();
        }                                   
    },

    self.next = function() {
        debugger;
        //get le min et le max
        var min = min_max(options.min_array_td_hide);
        var max = min_max(options.max_array_td_hide);
        // posibilité d'aller plus loin à droite ?
        if (max.max <= options.nb_col && max.max !== 0)
        {
            //on ajoute 1 de plus à gauche
            var index = min.max + 1;
            options.min_array_td_hide.push(index);
            $('th:nth-child('+index+'),td:nth-child('+index+')').hide();

            //on affiches celle de droite                                                                                                       
            options.max_array_td_hide = options.max_array_td_hide.filter(function(e) { return e !== max.min})
            $('th:nth-child(' + (max.min) + '),td:nth-child(' + (max.min) + ')').show();
        }                                               
    }
})
(window.grid = window.grid || {},
window.jQuery = window.jQuery);
```

and the CSS:

```
.grid-mvc {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.table{
    width: 700px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table td,
.table th
{
    /*width: 100px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    white-space: nowrap;                    
}
```

html grid is standard `table thead th tbody tr td`

My issue is on `arr.push($('td:nth-child(' + i + ')').width());` the returned width don't match with the `td` width in CSS, then the `array_hide` is wrong and all the mechanics is broken.

Then how to retrieve the right width of `td` ? 
And feel free to comment my script to increase his quality :)

EDIT :

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxnoq5y2/2/)

Comment: Can you leave this on jsfiddle ?

Comment: for nb_col you have selector on this: `$('.table tr:nth-child(1) td')` but inside the loop you are pushing the wrong one I guess. `$('td:nth-child(' + i + ')'`.. try to prepend this `.table tr:nth-child(1)` there,, something like: `$('.table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(' + i + ')')...`

Comment: No, nb_col retrieve only number of columns, but $('td:nth-child(' + i + ')').width() returns the width of each columns. Same behavior when I try with fully named $('.table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(' + i + ')')... The issue is width is different between init and render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some tries, I've found the good selector.

```
for (i = 1; i <= this.options.nb_col(this.jqContainer); i++) {
    arr.push(this.jqContainer.find('.table th:nth-child(' + i + ')').width());
};
```

The `th` have a good value of width but `td` doesn't at the init step.